# check the text in a Apache Velocity (.vm file) using java

Tags: java, apache, jsp, struts2, velocity

```
#set ($collegename = $parameters.get('collegename'))
```

when i print `$collegename` in vm file. it show college's names in some rows.
there are 20 college's names.
i want to put a condition on a particular college. when encounter this college name. it can not print the employee.

```
#if ($collegename!="xyzcollege")
$stack.findValue("getFullName('$employee')")
```

but it is not getting to check the "xyzcollege".
any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the end tag:-

```
#if ($collegename!="xyzcollege")
   $stack.findValue("getFullName('$employee')")
#end
```